# How to optimise my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table user_notification. There's a cron command running which executes

```
SELECT * FROM `user_notification` `t` WHERE `t`.`status`=2;
```

where status 1 - Send_fail, 2- Queue , 3- Success (like this.)

In the table there are around ~100K records which are increasing exponentially day by day. This query is taking too much time. Is there a way to optimise this query ?

```
#Table structure for table `user_notification`

CREATE TABLE `user_notification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notification_title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `notification_message` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `user_notification`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `notification_id` (`notification_id`);
ALTER TABLE `user_notification`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=94322;
ALTER TABLE `user_notification`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_notification_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_notification_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`notification_id`) REFERENCES `notification` (`id`);


# Query_time: 0.010663  Lock_time: 0.000045 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 17294
SET timestamp=1491527264;
SELECT * FROM `user_notification` `t` WHERE `t`.`status`=2;
```

Comment: The query is taking 0.01s to execute. That's not bad, but you still can create an index at column status.

Comment: @Manish why are you using `t` in your query `SELECT * FROM user_notification t WHERE t.status=2;` I think there is no need to use `aliases`

Comment: @user3441151 . . . Aliases are generally a good idea and should not be discouraged.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are correct. But I think there is no need to use `Aliases`.

Comment: Just for ease of work. I don't think that is making any contribution to query time. Yes query is taking not much time now, but when it will reach around 20-30 millions of record then it will slow down.

Comment: Prior to give an answer of the likes given below, a good idea would be to analyze the average repartition of records per status. Run `SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM user_notification GROUP BY status;` during interesting times for you and make percentages off it. If you find 20% (generic suggestion) or less of records with status = 2, you should create the index on the status column. Now, this is supposing the  query you're trying to improve does use status = 2 all the time, and not a placeholder for the status filter that would change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, creating an index on the `status` column should help.

It sounds like you are going to frequently be working with a relatively small subset of rows (that is, "queued" rows) in an increasingly huge table.  You might want to consider putting "queued" records in their own table, and then moving them into a history table as their status changes to "success" or "failed".  That way, you're only querying from a relatively small table.  Of course, this strategy involves extra deletes and inserts, so it may cause other problems depending on how your application works.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is executing in just 0.01s, which is pretty fast. If you want to optimize it anyways, there are a couple of things you can do. First of all, do you need all 8 columns everytime? Instead of using

```
SELECT  *
FROM    user_notification t
WHERE   t.status=2;
```

you should always list only the fields you actually need:

```
SELECT  user_id, notification_id, notification_title, notification_message, status /*change columns as needed*/
FROM    user_notification t
WHERE   t.status=2;
```

Other than that, you can create an index for the column status to speed up the query filtering.

```
ALTER TABLE user_notification 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX i1 ON user_notification (status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Index on column `status` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't queue it, just do it."

It is a common mistake to think that MySQL makes a good queuing system.

If the hassle of enqueuing and dequeuing items approximates the effort to simply perform the task, then do so.

OK, OK, you insist on have a queue?  Then either do as Jerrad suggests.  Or perhaps just have an extra table with things "waiting to be done".

When polling for something to do, be sure to watch out for transactional issues -- else two threads might grab and work on the same item.

Why did a 0.01s query show up in the slowlog?  Probably you turned on `log_queries_not_using_indexes`.  (I find that setting to be virtually useless, just clutter in the slowlog.)